# healthcare enrollment verification of claims

Tags: sql, sas, claims

All:
I'm trying to verify if a hospital stay should be covered based on enrollment data using SAS.

There are two tables:

1. "enr"  : 2 years of a binary (0/1) if the patient was enrolled on that month.

   ```
   data enr;
   input id year jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec;
   cards;
   1 2018 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
   1 2019 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   2 2018 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   2 2019 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
   ;
   ```
2. "clms" : id, admit_dt, discharge_dt, dr_id, cost

   ```
   data clms;
   input id admit_dt mmddyy10. @14dischrg_dt mmddyy10. code dr_id cost;
   format admit_dt dischrg_dt mmddyy10.; 
   cards;     
   1 02/01/2019 02/06/2019 470 2 800         
   1 06/01/2019 06/15/2019 251 30 400        
   2 10/18/2018 10/22/2018 871 5 250        
   2 05/18/2019 05/22/2019 999 3 1000 
   ;
   ```

For each "id" on the claims table, I wish to identify claims to be paid under the rule: for a paid claim, the patient must be enrolled in the 4 months prior and 4 months after the date of admission(admit_dt).

One of the tricky issues is the format of the months on the enrollment table(character, e.g."feb") differs from that of the admission date mmddyyy10 on the claims table.

Should I use an sql solution?

Comment: Hi - please don't post data as pictures; post as datalines, so users can easily use the data in examples/answers.

Comment: @Joe 
Thank you very much for the tip.  Duly noted.

Answer (score 0):

Transpose the `enr` data, compute which months are banded together, then perform a SQL join.

Example:

```
data enr_tall;
  set enr;
  array months jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec;
  do i = 1 to 12;
    month = mdy (i,1,year);
    enrolled = months[i];
    output;
  end;
  keep id month enrolled;
run;

data enr_tall_bands;
  set enr_tall;
  by id month;
  retain count4;

  if first.id then do;
    count4 = 0; 
    band + 1;
  end;

  if ^first.id and not enrolled and count4 > 0 then do;
    count4 = 0; 
    band + 1;
  end;

  if enrolled then do;
    if count4 = 0 then band + 1;
    count4 + 1;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
  create table news as
  select 
    clms.*
  , ( select count(distinct band) = 1 and min(enrolled) = 1
      from enr_tall_bands as bands
      where
          bands.id = clms.id
        & admit_dt between 
              intnx('month', month, -4) 
              and
              intnx('month', month, 4)
    ) as
      payable
  from clms;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This perfect.  I've been reading about the techniques used.  Thanks, again.

Comment: Be sure to accept and mark useful answers in stackoverflow.

Comment: I attempted to do so, but, received a message stating I need a "reputation of 15" for an up-vote to be recorded.